# Connect to embedded Printer in a PDA device

Tags: flutter, printing, pos

I am developing a flutter app to print receipt from a PDA device. The device is an Android 6.0 and has built in printer. I am trying to figure out how to connect to the printer to send printing command through esc_pos_printer https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_printer  flutter package. However, what I found only through Network or Bluetooth.

```
    const PaperSize paper = PaperSize.mm80;
final profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();
final printer = NetworkPrinter(paper, profile);

final PosPrintResult res = await printer.connect('192.168.0.123', port: 9100);
```

do you have any idea to connect to the printer
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to print with some other software configuration other than flutter? Why not look for something like that and port it to flutter?

Comment: Thanks, now I am looking to print through USB